# routing - making the controller a second element in the URL in codeigniter 2

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2, codeigniter-url

I'm setting up a new website where the website will have multiple microsites within them and need a URL structure which is:

http://www.example.com/microsite_name/controller/method/db_id/

for example I am creating a site which allows for multiple sports clubs and each sports club can have their own microsite which is then all controlled via the same installation. So it might be I have a url such as:

http://www.example.com/golf/events

and

http://www.example.com/baseball/events

I need a route to grab the microsite name so I can access it but then handle everything after it like a normal route to the controller and method.

Usually I would do something like:

```
$route['events/(:any)'] = "events/$1";
```

but I need to put something before the 'events' bit and i'm not sure what - can anyone help or point me to a how to?

I'm aware I can have multiple application directories but the microsites need to be dynamically generated....

Comment: Uhm...`(:any)` ? `$route['(:any)/events/(:any)'] = "events/$1/$2";` <-- adjust this accordingly. `$1` is the first match, `$2` the second

Comment: how did I not spot that. Thanks - saved me loads of time!